# Cassandra: unable to update a row with a non-primary key (even though I created an index.)

Tags: indexing, cassandra, cql

Currently getting this error message:

**Bad Request: Expected key 'KEY' to be present in WHERE clause for 'UserGameAnswers'**

```
cqlsh:godofsports> UPDATE UserGameAnswers SET 'status' = 'thing' WHERE 'event_question_id' = '7';
Bad Request: Expected key 'KEY' to be present in WHERE clause for 'UserGameAnswers'
```

Given that I have an index against this column key (see below) and that [this should be allowed](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/UPDATE) what am I doing wrong?

```
cqlsh:godofsports> DESCRIBE COLUMNFAMILY UserGameAnswers;

CREATE TABLE UserGameAnswers (
  KEY text PRIMARY KEY,
  event_question_id text
) WITH
  comment='' AND
  comparator=ascii AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  default_validation=text AND
  min_compaction_threshold=4 AND
  max_compaction_threshold=32 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' AND
  compression_parameters:sstable_compression='SnappyCompressor';

CREATE INDEX event_question_id_idx ON UserGameAnswers (event_question_id);
```

Do I need to make a query to fetch the actual KEYs first? :(

Comment: I'm fetching all of the keys by in other queries right now. It seems you can't use IN () with secondary indexes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you need to determine the key and write the update against that.